# How do I make it so when I insert a row to csv it adds it to another line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I'm trying to insert a new row to a csv file using pandas. It adds the data, but it doesn't make it into a new row for example

This is the current file:

```
id,balance
00,100
```

But when I insert a new row, it becomes like this:

```
id,balance
00,10001,0
```

I have tried adding \n to the id but it becomes like this:

```
id,balance
00,100"
01",0
```

This is my current code:

```
member_id = '\n' + str(member.id)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'id': [member_id], 
     'balance': [0]
})
     df1.to_csv('member_file.csv', mode = 'a', header = False, index = False)
```

How do I make it so it adds it to another line?

Comment: "using pandas"—please always include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking about Pandas, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g., Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g., Pandas and NumPy), please include it in the tags."

Answer (score 2):

Add a newline at the end of the file (before you call `to_csv`) with:

```
with open('member_file.csv', "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: To avoid blank lines, you may need to open the file in binary mode, seek to the last byte (`.seek(-1, 2)`) and check whether it's `\n` (or `\r`, depending on operating system), so you only add it when it's missing. Then you'll either need to add the correct newline per operating system, or re-open the file in text mode to do the addition.

Answer (score 0):

use pd.DataFrame.append()

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.append({
     'id': [member_id], 
     'balance': [0]
})
df1.to_csv('member_file.csv', mode = 'a', header = False, index = False)
```